# PHP only showing three of the four messages

Tags: php, mysql

I think I'm just missing the problem...

If I run this code it is supposed to show "username already exists" if there is already a username equal to what the user enters.

But so far, it only shows "successfully registered", "Please try again!" or "please fill all values" but it never shows "username already exists".. what do I have wrong here?

```
<?php

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

if($username == '' || $password == ''){
     echo 'please fill all values';
}
else{
     require_once('dbConnect.php');
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM HL WHERE username='$username'";

     $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

    if(isset($check)){
          echo 'username already exists';
    }
    else{ 
         $sql = "INSERT INTO HL(username,password) VALUES('$username','$password')";
         if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'successfully registered';
         }else{
            echo 'Please try again!';
         }
    }
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: check `var_dump ($check);` by providing existing username and tell

Comment: Never directly insert a variable into a query. Use prepared statements. Now you are vulnerable for SQL injection.

Comment: Also don't send username and password into URL. security issue

Comment: does `username` have spaces when you are sending it?

Comment: @Ivar does "prepared statement" mean a hashed value?

Comment: @Anant no it doesn't allow for it to have spaces

Comment: @JohanDewaal No. It means that you put a placeholder in the query, and send the value separately. [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) is one of the most used vulnerabilities. Read about how to use prepared statements in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: that `isset()` is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));

    if($check){
          echo 'username already exists';
    }
```

remove `isset` from that condition

Comment: I have removed it from the code but it still shows "successfully registered"..?